# The output not displaying after scanf() using c programming

Tags: c

Here im working on my first coding in c programming. I've got the problem when I want to get the user input and display the output from the user input. here my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Enter the number : ");
    int hallo = 0;
    scanf("%d", hallo);
    printf("hallo, %d", hallo);

}
```

after executing the code the last line not appear where is `prinf("hallo, %d", hallo);`. Which is to display the user input.

Comment: scanf("%d", &hallo); You need to pass address of `hallo` variable

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. See [mcve]_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th line of the code: `scanf("%d", hallo);`

Here `&hallo` should be used instead of just the variable name `hallo`.

The significance of the `&` sign is that it gives the address of a particular variable. So whatever the value is entered by the user, it will be stored at the address of the variable (in this case at the address of variable `hallo`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the & after the , in scanf
Like this 
scanf("%d", & hallo);

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
typedef struct{
    char name[30];
    int id;
    double salary;
} Employee;
 
  
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Number of employee to process: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);

    
    Employee employees[n];
 
    
    printf("Enter %d Employee Details \n \n",n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Employee %d:- \n",i+1);

        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",employees[i].name);

        printf("Id: ");
        scanf("%d",&employees[i].id);

        printf("Salary: ");
        scanf("%lf",&employees[i].salary);

        char ch = getchar();
 
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    printf("-------------- All Employees Details ---------------\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Name \t: ");
        printf("%s \n",employees[i].name);
 
        printf("Id \t: ");
        printf("%d \n",employees[i].id);
 
        printf("Salary \t: ");
        printf("%.2lf \n",employees[i].salary);
 
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This sample code is not a direct answer to the question.